# Can 4-character string literals and FourCC (aka OSType) values live together in peace and harmony?

Tags: delphi

I'm working with `RIFFCHUNK` structures, declared (in the "foreign" modules) as (citing `MMSystem` and `DirectShow9`):

```
  type FOURCC = DWORD;                    { a four character code }

  type _riffchunk = record
    fcc: FOURCC;
    cb: DWORD;
  end;
  type RIFFCHUNK = _riffchunk;
```

My particular interest here is `fcc` field, which type resolves to `LongWord`. In the other hand, meaningful values for `fcc` are strings comprised by 4 ASCII printable single-byte characters. I'd like to avoid the following ugliness (citing `MMSystem`):

```
  const FOURCC_RIFF = $46464952;   { 'RIFF' }
```

... and use actual, self-explaining four character string literals for assignment and comparison.

What have I tried so far and got stuck shown below:

```
const idRIFF: packed array [1..4] of AnsiChar = 'RIFF';
var Chunk: RIFFCHUNK;
begin
  Chunk.fcc := FOURCC(idRIFF);  { works, but requires a typecast in implementation }
```

Since `idRIFF` isn't true constant, it cannot be used in declaration of properly typed symbol.

**So, I'd like to ask an advice where to go further in this beautification affair?**

Please note what `FOURCC` type is "foreign", so I cannot just redeclare it as character array.

Comment: The name of the constant `FOURCC_RIFF` is clear enough in my view, so I would do nothing at all (assuming I wouldn't read its value frequently). Many people use constants like `E_NOTIMPL`, `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` etc. every day and I bet just a few of them cares how "ugly" their values are. Though it's an interesting question...

Comment: @TLama, I think you are missing my point. Take a look at `FOURCC_RIFF` declaration once again. Unless there is a explaining comment or you just know ASCII table and endianess by heart, this declaration is definitely less clear than it would be in C (see Remy's answer about `MAKEFOURCC`/`mmioFOURCC` macros) as demonstrated in `mmsystem.h`.

Comment: Since I don't know how you need to use it, as comment. Maybe something like this would be an option? `Type TFCC=
packed array [1..4] of AnsiChar;

type
  FOURCC = Record
   case integer of
     0:(DW: DWORD);
     1:(AC: TFCC);
     2:(Byte:Array[0..3] of Byte);
  End;

  type _riffchunk = record
    fcc: FOURCC;
    cb: DWORD;
  end;`

Comment: It's quite interesting to see different people's takes on beauty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also write:

```
_riffchunk.fcc := PCardinal(PAnsiChar('RIFF'))^;
```

Yes, it works!

This is in fact the same as writing:

```
const
  FOURCC_RIFF: PAnsiChar = 'RIFF';
...
  _riffchunk.fcc := PCardinal(FOURCC_RIFF)^;
```

So with a function you have:

```
function ToFourCC(const s: AnsiString): FOURCC; inline;
begin
  result := PCardinal(s)^;
end;

_riffchunk.fcc := ToFourCC('RIFF');
```

Of course, all this won't work with the NextGen compiler.

Answer (score 4):

This declaration will treat FOURCC_RIFF as a constant using a string literal:

```
const
  FOURCC_RIFF_S : array[0..SizeOf(FOURCC)-1] of AnsiChar = 'RIFF';
var
  FOURCC_RIFF : FOURCC absolute FOURCC_RIFF_S;
```

If writable constant directive is on, that could be fixed by catching the compiler directive as well.

```
{$IFOPT J+}
  {$DEFINE UNDO_WRCONST}
  {$J-}
{$ENDIF}
const
  FOURCC_RIFF_S : array[0..SizeOf(FOURCC)-1] of AnsiChar = 'RIFF';
var
  FOURCC_RIFF : FOURCC absolute FOURCC_RIFF_S;
{$IFDEF UNDO_WRCONST}
  {$J+}
{$ENDIF}
```

No typecasting needed and compiler treats the value as a true constant.

```
var
  Chunk: RIFFCHUNK;
...
  Chunk.fcc := FOURCC_RIFF;
```

Comment: absolute pretty much is a typecast. In C++ terms it is reinterp_cast. The typecast is much better than the absolute. The cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, well in a beauty contest, the beauty is in the eye of the beholder :-). I try to avoid typecasts when I can to get better readability and a higher degree of safety. The absolute keyword on the other hand, should only be used when the compiler stops you from improving readability.

Comment: You cannot avoid a typecast here (or a moral equivalent like `absolute` or `Move`). I personally think that the only way to improve readability is to encapsulate the typecast. Leaving it out front for all to see is what @Free was trying to avoid. I think.

Answer (score 3):

The multimedia API defines [`MAKEFOURCC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`mmioFOURCC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macros, both of which convert 4 characters into a `FOURCC` value, eg:

```
Chunk.fcc := MAKEFOURCC('R', 'I', 'F', 'F');
```

```
Chunk.fcc := mmioMAKEFOURCC('R', 'I', 'F', 'F');
```

In case Delphi does not have an existing translation in the `MMSystem` unit (it should, but I cannot check right now), here is one:

```
function MAKEFOURCC(ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3: AnsiChar): LongWord;
begin
  Result := LongWord(Ord(ch0)) or (LongWord(Ord(ch1)) shl 8) or (LongWord(Ord(ch2)) shl 16) or (LongWord(Ord(ch3)) shl 24); 
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of anything better than a helper function:

```
function FourCCfromString(const Value: AnsiString): FOURCC;
begin
  if Length(Value)<>SizeOf(Result) then
    raise ESomeException.Create(...);
  Move(Pointer(Value)^, Result, SizeOf(Result));
end;
```

The benefits that I can see are:

1. No casting at the call site. All the dirtiness is encapsulated in the helper.
2. No need to declared any new types – you can use plain old strings.

---

I don't think you can use record helpers with class operators here. You cannot define a class operator in a record helper.

You could define a record with `Implicit` class operators to perform conversions. It would look like this:

```
type
  TMyFourCC = record
    Value: FOURCC;
    class operator Implicit(const Value: AnsiString): TMyFourCC;
    class operator Implicit(const Value: string): TMyFourCC;
    class operator Implicit(const Value: TMyFourCC): FOURCC;
  end;
```

But then you'd need to write:

```
Chunk.fcc := 'RIFF';
```

and that won't compile because the compiler cannot infer that you want to go from `string` to `TMyFourCC` and then on to `FOURCC`. Unfortunately implicit conversion operators only allow a single hop.

Comment: Honestly, I love types :) In the helper function (started using right now) type can serve a purpose and restrict string argument to the certain length.

Comment: You'll still need a cast I think. Wouldn't bother me.

Comment: I'm doing a cast inside the helper to avoid `Move`. But actual literal string parameter of exactly 4 chars gets passed to the helper w/o cast (at least on XE2 32bit), so the helper actually improves code tidiness.